# Declaring constant in one useEffect cannot be used in another useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

i am currently using socket.io to create a chat app and i have stumbled onto a problem that the socket keeps initializing if declared outside my useEffect and when declared inside my useEffect i am not able to use it anywhere else.

```
    const[socket,setSocket]=useState(null)
    const[records,setRecords]=useState([])

useEffect(()=> {
            axios
            .get('/api/messages/',{headers:{"auth-token":localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}})
                .then(res => {
                    setRecords(res.data)
                    console.log(records)
                })
                .catch(err =>
                    console.log(err)      
                )

                    // main socket       
    const newsocket =io.connect(CONNECTION_PORT)

    newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
        setSocket(newsocket)
        console.log(`Admin ${ADMIN.id} is waiting. socketID: ${newsocket.id}`)
     });

      newsocket.emit('waiting', ADMIN.id);

      return(()=>{
        console.log(`admin: ${ADMIN.id} --- socketid ${newsocket.id} deleted`)
        newsocket.close()
    });

    },[]);

useEffect(()=>{

      socket.on("socketListening", (msg) => { //Error Occurs here !!!!
          console.log(msg)
      
          try{
                  const result = records.find(e=>e.id===msg.conversationId)
                  console.log(result)
                  const resultMessages=result.Messages;      
                  const newMessages =[msg,...resultMessages]
                  result.Messages=newMessages;
                  result.lastMessage=msg.message;
                  if(msg.senderId!==ADMIN.id){
                      result.Recipient=false;
                    }else{
                      result.Recipient=true;

                    }
                  console.log(result);
                  const arraywithoutrecord = records.filter(e=>e.id!==msg.conversationId)
                  setRecords([result,...arraywithoutrecord])
          }catch(e){
              console.log(e)
          }
      })

    },[records])
```

Error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')

Comment: I think reason is that state updates are async  so setSocket(newsocket) in your first useEffect doesn't run immediately so socket state will be still null in second effect. You can add optional chaining like:  socket?.on(...)

Comment: @Javokhir and by adding the ? how does the code flow?

Comment: First time when we try to socket?.on() or null?.on nothing happens. Then during next render, socket will be available and your code works

Comment: @Javokhir but now on first render socketListening event doesnt work

Comment: It's normal that it will be null in the guest render, you can't do anything about it